# LetsEncrypt web server authentication issue when trying to install SSL

Tags: authentication, ssl, lets-encrypt

I need to prove that I own the domain that will be covered by this SSL certificate so I need to create a file with a specific name and containing specific content, but I can't seem to get it right.

I'm being asked for the following

> Make sure your web server displays the following content at
>   http://www.domain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/7xLLYjA7YGAvkCaASuJQl6PE8nHYFh6TBvyMRD3 before continuing:
>
> [Long String That I'm Being Asked To Display Here]

So through Filezilia where all of my site files are, I made a separate directory for the following with acme-challenge in the .well-known directory and so on

.well-known

acme-challenge

7xLLYjA7YGAvkCaASuJQl6PE8nHYFh6TBvyMRD3

Then in the directory 7xLLYjA7YGAvkCaASuJQl6PE8nHYFh6TBvyMRD3 I created a file with the title of the [Long String That I'm Being Asked To Display] and entered it as the content of the text file as well.

But when I go to enter and get LetsEncrypt to check the authentication, I get the following message

> Self-verify of challenge failed.

Am I doing this completely wrong or am I on the right track here?

Answer (score 3):

```
/.well-known/acme-challenge/7xLLYjA7YGAvkCaASuJQl6PE8nHYFh6TBvyMRD3
 ^ directory ^ directory    ^ file
```

The `token` is a file, not a directory. It seems you're using manual mode with (S)FTP. Do you have shell access? If yes, you could run a client that automates the creation of a file. You can either run the [official client](https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/) that you already seem to be using or any other client from the [list of available clients](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/list-of-client-implementations/2103?u=kelunik).

If you have no shell access, I think there are also clients automating it from a remote machine to upload files via (S)FTP. But if you don't have shell access, you will probably have an issue with installing your certificate automatically.

Generally, you get more help posting to the official support form at https://community.letsencrypt.org.